# Getting deployment error when deploying sample script in Developer composer playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to setup the development environment for composer by following the steps in the tutorial. I was able to generate the .bna file successfully and use it in the online playground. But when I try to deploy the .bna file to the fabric V1.0 running in my local, I get the below error.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-83:~/fabric-tools/my-network$ cd dist
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-83:~/fabric-tools/my-network/dist$ composer network 
deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString

Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: my-network@0.0.1
    Description: The Hello World of Hyperledger Composer samples

events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: event message must be properly signed by an identity from the same organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator: [Expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received ]]
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:634:14
```

My docker images are as follows:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-83:~/fabric-tools/my-network/dist$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                          COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            
NAMES
80c9949edf73        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-beta      "peer 
node start -..."   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051-
>7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
126f6381cc90        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0-beta   "tini -- 
/docker-e..."   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
924081546fa1        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-beta        "sh -c 
'fabric-ca-..."   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054-
>7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
d13f2c8e8421        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-beta   "orderer"                
19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           
orderer.example.com
```

Node version is: 4.2.6
npm version is : 3.5.2
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to be at the latest Node level - you're currently at 4.2.6 - you need to be at node version 6.x
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html

I assume you're using Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.0x LTS ..

Comment: Sorry my node version is v6.11.0

Comment: can I check that you have you actually created a hlfv1 connection profile for the user you're trying to connect with - see hlfv1 docs page here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/connectionprofile.html (it has a sample profile for hlfv1 near the end)

Comment: I believe this step is needed only when I connect to my custom fabric network. I was following the tutorials in composer website and I hope the profiles and fabric setup is done automatically by composer. Am I supposed to establish a new connection profile even when I follow the steps mentioned in setting up development environment in the tutorial?

Comment: If you look in the file ~/.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1/connection.json there will be a directory defined for the property 'keyValStore'. Could you delete that directory and re-run createComposerProfile.sh and try again. It's possible you had an old PeerAdmin credential in that folder which isn't valid for that level of fabric

Comment: I tried it. In fact i deleted everything and did a fresh install.